# How do I unlike a level?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

I accidentally clicked "I like it" on a level in Super Mario Maker 2 and want to undo it. I tried clicking the boo button and the button again, but it had no effect. How do I undo liking a level in Super Mario Maker 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there's no current way to unlike/unboo a level you previously voted. Which is quite stupid.
Many [Reddit users](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/d0d8w3/i_accidentally_booed_a_level_i_really_liked/) complained about it in the years.